# запуск билда на одной машине с jenkins

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, devops, ci-cd

Всем привет, пытаюсь разобраться с jenkins. У меня есть job, который генерирует исполняемый файл сервера. Мне нужно сразу после сборки запустить сервер на этой же машине.
Я столкнулся с двумя проблемами:

1. Я могу запустить сервер в фоновом режиме, но не могу получить доступ к процессу обратно при новой сборке(я хочу безопасно останавливать мой сервер отправкой определенного слова в stdin на мой сервер. Я мог бы использовать вместо этого колбэк, который реагирует на сигнал от ос, но мне интересно разобраться, как сделать таким способом).
2. По каким-то причинам исполняемый файл не всегда запускается, при этом, вроде как, нет никаких ошибок. Это связано именно с запуском в фоне, потому что когда я не использую &, то все всегда работает отлично.

Код в моем job:

```
go build -o ../server ./cmd
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
nohup ../server &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблемы следующим образом:

1. Получить доступ к процессу обратно не получилось, перепробовал все, но видимо если процесс имеет supproccess, то ни одна программа не сможет сделать, то что мне нужно. В итоге я просто встроил ssh сервер на сервер моего сервиса и теперь просто подключаюсь по ssh и шлю нужную команду.
2. Я не понял по каким причинам сервер не всегда стартовал в фоне из дженкинса, но помогло sleep 5 после команды запуска сервера. Возможно можно написать более умный скрипт, который будет каждую секунду чекать запущен ли процесс и останавливать свое выполнение только после того, как сервер будет запущен